# Order all union results by timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

The query is

```
SELECT L.timestamp AS timestamp . . . 
FROM like AS L 
INNER JOIN users AS U 
ON U.id = L.user_id 
INNER JOIN posts AS P 
ON P.user_id = :userid 
WHERE L.post_id = P.id 
  UNION 
SELECT P.timestamp . . . 
FROM post AS P 
INNER JOIN users AS U 
ON U.id = P.user_id 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:userid , P.users) 
  UNION 
SELECT C.timestamp AS timestamp . . . 
FROM comment AS C 
INNER JOIN posts AS P 
ON P.user_id = :userid 
INNER JOIN users AS U 
ON U.id = C.user_id 
WHERE C.post_id = P.id 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

I tried adding the `ORDER BY timestamp DESC` at the end but it still isn't showing the latest one first. It's showing one from; 10 days ago, 9 days ago, 1 month ago, and 4 days ago, in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the query as sub-query to do an `ORDER BY` on the whole result:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT L.timestamp AS timestamp FROM like AS L 
        INNER JOIN users AS U ON U.id = L.user_id 
        INNER JOIN posts AS P ON P.user_id = :userid 
    WHERE L.post_id = P.id 
    UNION
    SELECT P.timestamp . . . FROM post AS P 
        INNER JOIN users AS U ON U.id = P.user_id 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:userid , P.users) 
    UNION 
    SELECT C.timestamp AS timestamp . . . 
    FROM comment AS C 
        INNER JOIN posts AS P ON P.user_id = :userid 
        INNER JOIN users AS U ON U.id = C.user_id 
    WHERE C.post_id = P.id 
)x ORDER BY x.timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to put the entire query in a `from` clause.  You can just put parentheses around each subquery.  This is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION
>   result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the
>   ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one.

So:

```
(SELECT L.timestamp AS timestamp . . . 
 FROM like L JOIN
      users U 
      ON U.id = L.user_id JOIN
      posts P 
      ON P.user_id = :userid 
 WHERE L.post_id = P.id 
) UNION
(SELECT P.timestamp . . . 
 FROM post P JOIN
      users U 
      ON U.id = P.user_id 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:userid , P.users) 
) UNION 
(SELECT C.timestamp AS timestamp . . . 
 FROM comment C JOIN
      posts P 
      ON P.user_id = :userid JOIN
      users U 
      ON U.id = C.user_id 
 WHERE C.post_id = P.id 
)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Note:  If your subqueries are not returning duplicate rows, then change the `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.  There is no need to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: Yes this is also possible. I tried different things based on the documentation. Do you know what is happening here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77fff9/11/1? The `ORDER BY` is working without sub-query and parentheses (but not expected since the documentation describes another way to `ORDER BY` on `UNION`).

Comment: @SebastianBrosch . . . I actually think for `union all` the parentheses are not needed.  This seems to be a quirk in MySQL.